# HTML with Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

Im trying to use prawn to generate a PDF of a log entry, then entries are stored in bbcode ([b]bold[/b] etc...) and is converted to html on display.

Is there any way to display the html in prawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [prawn-format](http://github.com/sandal/prawn-format) might be what you're looking for, but you'll need to use an older version of prawn if you want to try it out.

Comment: Yeah ive decided to use that as a base for an extension my bbcode gem

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably get the best results if you use a lexical analyser such as 'Syntax' by Jamis Buck (http://syntax.rubyforge.org/) and parse the interesting parts of the HTML chunk and render those parts to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.princexml.com/ to convert html docs to css, or use the princely plugin to render a pdf as one of the accepted formats of your view. See http://jimneath.org/2009/02/16/creating-pdf-documents-in-ruby-on-rails/

If you are wanting to use prawn directly I don't think there is a way to just use html directly to convert to pdf.

Comment: Prince XML would cost 3800 USD for my application... which is about 3800 USD above my budget