# How to generate a PDF mail merge with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf

I'm working on a very simple mail merge system with Ruby on Rails. I have 2 models (members and letters).

First I create a html-formatted letter with some special fields (like {NAME}, {ADDRESS} or {CITY}.

Then, I must generate a PDF with one letter per member. So, if I have 100 members in the database, the PDF must have 100 letters, each one customized (replacing the special fields with the data in the database).

I know how to create the letters in html, but I don't know how to generate the PDF. Can you help me with that? I know there are some gems to create PDFs, but I don't know how to add the letters on different pages.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) to generate PDFs and it sounds like it would work for you. There’s a [wiki article](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/wiki/Using-Prawn-in-Rails-3) on using Prawn with Rails.

The `go_to_page` method will let you position elements on a particular page after you have used `add_pages` to create them.

Comment: Perfect!! I've done it with Prawn, and it works perfectly. Only one more question: is possible to render HTML formatted text with Prawn?

Comment: [Looks like no.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019793/html-with-prawn) Prawn/PDFs in general allow more precise control of layout than HTML with CSS, but with the price of needing that precision to be specified. When I’ve wanted to have the same HTML for browser and print, I’ve resorted to scripting a browser to save as PDF, ugh.